# SQL Azure Export/Bacpacs and Foreign Key Integrity

Tags: sql-server, database, azure, azure-sql-database, bacpac

I've a bit of a strange problem with a BACPAC I took last night using the SQL Azure Import/Export Service.

In our database there are 2 related tables.

```
dbo.Documents --All Documents in the database
  Id
  DocName
  Extension

dbo.ProcessDocuments --Doc's specific to a process
  Id
  DocumentId (FK -> dbo.Documents.Id with Check Constraint)
  ProcessId
```

Based on that Schema it should not be possible for the `ProcessDocuments` table to include a row that does not have a companion entry in the main `Documents` table.

However after I did the restore of the database in another environment I ended up with

7001 entries in `ProcessDocuments`. Only 7000 equivalent entries for them in `Documents` (missing 1). And the restore failed on attempting to restore the `ALTER TABLE CHECK CONSTRAINT` on `ProcessDocuments`

The only thing I can imagine is that when the backup was being taken, it was sequentially (alphabetically???) going through the tables, and backing up the data 1 table at a time and something like the following happened.

- `Documents` gets backed up. Contains 7000 entries
- Someone adds a new process document to the system / Insert to `Documents` & `Process Documents`
- `ProcessDocuements` gets backed up. Contains 7001 entries

If that's the case, then it creates a massive problem in terms using BACPACs as a valid disaster recovery asset, because if they're taken while the system has data in motion, it's possible that your BACPAC contains data integrity issues.

Is this the case, or can anyone shed any light on what else could have caused this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Data export uses bulk operations on the DB and is NOT guaranteed to be transactional, so issue like you described can and eventually will happen.

"An export operation performs an individual bulk copy of the data from each table in the database so does not guarantee the transactional consistency of the data. You can use the Windows Azure SQL Database copy database feature to make a consistent copy of a database, and perform the export from the copy."
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh335292.aspx

---

if you want to create transactionally consistent backups you have to copy the DB first (which may cost you a lot, depending on size of your db) and then export a copied DB as BACPAC (as ramiramilu pointed out) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj650016.aspx

you can do it yourself or use [RedGate SQL Azure Backup](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dba/sql-azure-backup/) but from what I understand they follow exactly the same steps as described above, so if you choose their consistent backup option it's gonna cost you as well.

Comment: Is there any way to create a transactionally consistent backup from SQL Azure then. (without completely shutting down all the application front-ends and killing all running transactions on the server)

Comment: Can you try Database Copy - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj650016.aspx. that will give you transactionally consistent backup. Once you create a copy database, you can make a backpack and send it to Azure Storage - http://sqlsailor.com/2013/08/19/wasdbackups/ and restore it from the storage.

Comment: The Copy/Export tool in the Management portal still just seems to create a bacpac file that has the same integrity issues as if I had made the bacpac myself in SQL Management Studio. Each bacpac I make has a foreign key constraint failure in a different table.  The 'Copy Database' option in Management Studio isn't available when connected to an Azure database.  I don't understand the point of a bacpac if they're not guaranteed to be consistent.

Answer (score 1):

As per the answer from Slav, the bacpac is non-transactional and will be corrupted if any new rows are added to any table while the bacpac is being generated.

To avoid this:

1) Copy the target database, which will return straight away, but the database will take some time to copy.  This operation will create a full transactional copy:

```
CREATE DATABASE <name> AS COPY OF <original_name>
```

2) Find the status of your copy operation:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_database_copies
```

3) Generate a bacpac file on the copied database, which isn't being used by anyone.

4) Delete the copied database, and you'll have a working bacpac file.

Comment: Thanks, yeah this is the road I've gone down but it has the crappy implication of the copy existing for a short period of time per day which doubles our SQL Azure Bill each month if we're doing daily backups